# How to fix 405 Method Not Allowed in forms, using Blueprint in Flask

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, blueprint

I have a file upload form in HTML, which should be used to upload and save to a static folder. The problem is that it works fine in a simple Flask app, but it just **doesn't work using Blueprint templates**.

I have tried several different ways of making this work. When I use "**url_for**", the page doesn't even load (**werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'upload'. Did you mean 'forms_blueprint.upload' instead?**).

But when I change "url_for" to "**form_upload.html**", the result is always that the **method is not allowed**.

All thoughts are appreciated.

## routes.py:

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/home/juliosouto/flask-gentelella/app/uploaded_files/'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER


@blueprint.route('/<template>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def route_template(template):
    return render_template('form_upload' + '.html')


@blueprint.route('/upload', methods=['POST','GET'])
def upload():
    file = request.files['file']
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```

## form_upload.html:

```
<form action ="{{ url_for('upload') }}" class= "dropzone" name="file" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data"></form>
```

I need the file to be saved to a static folder.

Comment: your upload route defaults to a GET request, but does not seem to provide a render_template or return. Also, you would want to do something like if request.method == Post before handling the file upload and then return to Get method or any other route.

Comment: @gittert, I have tried those too. None worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I use "url_for", the page doesn't even load (werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'upload'. Did you mean 'forms_blueprint.upload' instead?).

This means exactly what it says.  when you build the URL you need to do it as follows:

```
{{ url_for('forms_blueprint.upload') }}
```

---

Also, as @gittert correctly states, your upload route returns nothing.

This should render a template, or return a redirect to someplace else.

Comment: Perfect, @v25. I couldn't imagine it was literal. It worked and solved the problem right away!